# Swift Syntax for let (hello, world):(String,String) = ("hello","world")

Tags: swift

In Swift, what kind of syntax is below?

```
let (hello, world):(String,String) = ("hello","world")
print(hello) //prints "hello"
print(world) //prints "world"
```

Is it shorthand for:

```
let hello = "hello"
let world = "world"
```

If it is a shorthand, what is this shorthand called? Is there any Swift documentation to this type of styntax?

Comment: hm. then how come i can print out each var separately as if they are declaredly individually: print(hello) //prints "hello" print(world) //prints "world"

Comment: From the documentation: *You can decompose a tuple’s contents into separate constants or variables, which you then access as usual:*

Answer (score 2):

As noted by [@vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266465/swift-syntax-for-let-hello-worldstring-string-hello-world/37269351#comment62060845_37266465), what you're doing is creating a tuple – and then immediately [decomposing its contents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID329) into separate constants.

If you split the expression up, you may see what's going on better:

```
// a tuple – note that you don't have to specify (String, String), just let Swift infer it
let helloWorld = ("hello", "world")

print(helloWorld.0) // "hello"
print(helloWorld.1) // "world"

// a tuple decomposition – hello is assigned helloWorld.0, world is assigned helloWorld.1
let (hello, world) = helloWorld

print(hello) // "hello"
print(world) // "world"
```

However because you're decomposing the tuple's contents immediately upon creating the tuple, it kind of defeats the purpose of having a tuple to begin with. I would always prefer just to write:

```
let hello = "hello"
let world = "world"
```

Although if you prefer to write:

```
let (hello, world) = ("hello", "world")
```

That's absolutely up to you – it's a matter of personal preference.